# How can I replace arguments.callee; in javascript

Tags: javascript

This is my code

```
function add(x) {
    return function (y) {
        if (typeof y !== 'undefined') {
            x = x + y;
            return arguments.callee;
        } else {
            return x;
        }
    };
}
add(1)(2)(3)(4)();
```

Comment: Please don't use `arguments.callee`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee

Comment: can u please tell me the alternative?

Comment: `function(){ retrun arguments.calee; }` could be `function x(){ retrun x; }`

Answer (score 1):

As replace in - give it a name?:

```
function add(x) {
    return function my_func(y) {
        //          ^ Named function
        if (typeof y !== 'undefined') {
            x = x + y;
            return my_func;
        } else {
            return x;
        }
    };
}
add(1)(2)(3)(4)();
```

Also please read:

> Please don't use `arguments.callee`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee